# Update value in nested object using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs

My desire is to update the *products* inside the *shoppingCart[0]* 
The state: `const [authenticatedUser, setAuthenticatedUser] = useContext<any>(UserContext)`

`console.log(authenticatedUser)` displays the following:
[image]

I've tried updating the value of the products array with the following code: 
`setAuthenticatedUser({ ...authenticatedUser, products: ['new item'] })`
But it creates a new product array inside the authenticatedUser.

How can I update the products array inside `authenticatedUser.shoppingCart[0].products` ?

**Data:**

```
const [authenticatedUser, setAuthenticatedUser] = useState(
   {
    authenticated: true,
    id: "3i4jijrifjifrjifr",
    shoppingCart: [{
        createdAt: "2021-01-29T10:14:21.253Z",
        products: ['this is the array i want to update', '2', '3']
    }]
   }
)
```

Comment: you need to use useState, not useContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
setAuthenticatedUser({ ...authenticatedUser, shoppingCart:[{...authenticatedUser.shoppingCart[0],products:['newItem']}] })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const authenticatedUserCopy = { ...authenticatedUser }
authenticatedUserCopy.shoppingCart[0].products = ['new product']
setAuthenticatedUser(authenticatedUserCopy)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{ 
    ...authenticatedUser,
    shoppingCart: authenticatedUser.shoppingCart.map(s => { //map all items
        return {
            ...s,
            products: [...s.products, 'new item'] //add item
        }
    })
}
```